# highcharts drilldown not run on django,

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts, django-templates

I've tried other graphics and if they work, but the drilldown not run.
Url: http://aicapitals.cl/grafico/

In my template I have:

```
{% block javascript %}
    //here the code http://jsfiddle.net/yw4Vh/
{% endblock javascript %}

{% block content %}
    <script src="http://github.highcharts.com/bdf6471/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.highcharts.com/bdf6471/modules/drilldown.src.js"></script>
    <div id="container1" style="height: 300px"></div>
    <div id="container2" style="height: 300px; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
{% endblock content %}
```

the div id="container2" not show the graphs

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo.

Comment: Sebastian, please could you review my web http://aicapitals.cl/grafico/

Comment: First update Highcharts to 4.0.4 version. Then problem is with your  `parsed` method - you have an error in console.. `columns[1] = $.map(columns[1] ... )` - there isn't `columns[1]`, only `columns[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new file html and I pasted the code, and it ran ! I don't know how (the code was same)